# How to specify a float/decimal value for a column inside an insert in liquibase changelog?

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal, database-migration, liquibase

I'm just starting to learn liquidbase, I wrote a changeset with an insert, here's part of it:

```
databaseChangeLog:
...

- changeset:
  id: "all_types_table"
  changes:
  - createTable:
    tableName: "all_types_table"
    ...
  - insert:
    tableName: all_types_table
    columns:
  - column:
    name: float_column
    valueNumeric: 1.1
    ...
```

During the migration process, liquibase sets a parameter in JdbcDriver for this column with type double and not float. Same issue with the decimal type.

I tried using 'value' instead of 'valueNumber', adding quotes, and adding the literal 'f' to the number, but nothing worked.

Then I debugged and came to the "liquibase.change.ColumnConfig" class - inside this class the 'valueNumeric' that I specified inside the changelog is parsed. Inside, the NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).parse(value) method is called, which returns either Long or Double.

Is it possible to set the float/decimal parameter using changelog.yaml, without using sql files?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What's wrong with a double?

Comment: I'm testing a functionality where it is important to test different types of database columns. Therefore, I need to be able to migrate using liquibase not only double. Plus, in the following code, valueNumeric is checked through instanceof for all types of numbers, it seemed strange to me that when parsing only long or double is obtained

Comment: Whether JDBC uses a float or a double doesn't affect the type of the column in the DB. That is determined by your create table statement.

Comment: The parameters are bound inside the liquibase.statement.ExecutablePreparedStatementBase class in the applyColumnParameter method, in which the numbers are checked through instanceof, after which the corresponding setter in PreparedStatement is called (e.g. setDouble, setFloat, setBigDecimal). I'm using the YDB database, the appropriate types are explicitly set inside the driver implementation

Comment: But how is the table defined? What is your actual question? And BTW where does 'decimal' come into this?

Comment: So you are concerned that `PreparedStatement.setDouble` is being called by liquibase instead of `PreparedStatement.setFloat`? Why are you worried about this?